# Building S-Curves for projects in Excel using functions on dates and expected completion percentages

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, project-management

I have some data about projects that are guesstimated. This is a simple management of many unmanaged projects.

A project has a start and an end date, then a grid with Date, Planned %, and Actual %.

[image: excel sheet]

The planned is zero at the begin date and 100% at the end date, I'm trying to have an S-Curve in my graph with calculations from the begin date, the end date, and the date column.

[image: S-Curve]
I tried many EXP and LN functions, some trigonometric function, but nothing looks right.

Is there a formula I can plug into the cells in the "Planned" column to get a curve that makes sense?

Comment: Why not make a set of data : the example s curve you show looks about right , then just scale that data with the info ie start and end dates that you know.  Have you tried the forecast function?

Comment: That draws a straight line with points at 0%,50%, and 100%.

Comment: So, you made a set of data to show that s curve, then you get a straight line...

Comment: I'm with Mike - use whatever you used to get the graph you've shown.  Otherwise, the integral of the normal distribution gives a nice S-shaped curve. It's a built-in function in Excel called the Cumulative Normal Distribution, or something close to that. It isn't available for use as a data fitting function, you'll have to plot it separately, and scale it appropriately.  Ask a question about "least squares fit" if you don't know how to do that.

Comment: added an answer as a community wiki...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the commenters, the curve I had was an image from Wikipedia.

If the start to end date were scaled to numbers between 0 and 1, and using `=1/(1+EXP(-(X*12-6)))` I get a nice exponential curve that was too narrow (blue curve).

Modified it as `=1/(1+EXP(-($B4*12-6)*$D$1)*$D$2)` but it started at 4.74% and ended at 95.26%. (orange curve)

Scaling a bit more makes it much better (green curve). Projects start slowly, progress, then end slowly. Comparing this curve with a smoothed estimated completion percentages curve makes sense.

[image: S-Curves in Excel]

Comment: A well known and fairly simple equation for a sigmoid curve is the [Logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) `=A/(1+exp(-k*(x-x0))`.  A is the maximum value, k is the steepness of the curve, and x0 is the midpoint.  You got close by reinventing the wheel, but the function is simpler.

Comment: This makes sense, I was tweaking multipliers and using complicated "tricks"...